# Site is down and cant connect through SSH

Tags: ssh, wordpress, bitnami

I use Wordpress Bitnami solution for hosting WP sites. There were two accidents that happened only on two sites yet but it was repeating itself. Now one of them is okey, never happened once. The problem is that while connecting to site saying that it can't be reached. If I try to connect to instance through SSH it simply saying that is connecting but you can wait even 1 Hour and nothing changes. So I thought it was problem with google cloud servers? Or someone is DDoS'ing server or something like that? I would really be happy if you could help us to solve this!

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't given enough information to help solve the problem. What's your domain name? What has changed on the server recently? Have you tried ssh'ing in from another server in the same subnet, another Google virtual server I think based on context? Do you have backups of your server or database? I doubt the problem is Google cloud.

Comment: SHTP.fr

I tracked all the logins, activity on website, nothing strange. Database doesn't have anything unusual and any unusual activity too.

Comment: I can ssh to your server. Obviously I don't have user / password so I can't log in, but I get a login prompt. Problem is likely at the client side, check your computer / router / corporate firewall. Try another computer as well.

Comment: Yes you can now cause I restarted instance and it refixes it. I am talking what could cause problem

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. You can troubleshoot the server's performance by using the ps, free and df commands. Multiple reasons can cause that outage but it's easier to debug the problem when having more information. You can find the specific commands to run into your instance in [this page of our documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/faq/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-server-performance/) but feel free to add any other information when posting your question here